# implementing socket.io with Flutter and nodejs

Tags: node.js, flutter, sockets

I would like to create an application using socket io and flutter.
my server is in nodejs and the client flutter. after initialization, nothing happens. I used the socket_io_client: ^1.0.1 package from flutter and node js. Maybe I made a mistake somewhere? I deployed the server on heroku

```
//sever node
const app = require('express')()

const http = require('http').createServer(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.send("Node Server is running. Yay!!")
})

io.on('connection',socket => {
    console.log('a user connected'); 
    });
```

```
void main() {
  IO.Socket socket = IO.io('https://xxxherokuapp.com/');
  //print(socket.connected);
  socket.onConnect((_) {
    print(socket.connected);
    print('connect');
    socket.emit('msg', 'test');
  });
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

when i run the app, nothing happened. Maybe I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You don't start a server, that is why nothing happens. You can use the following code.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.send("Node Server is running. Yay!!")
})

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
});

server.listen(80, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:80');
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I did start the server. I had omitted to put in AndroidManifest.xml this line  `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" ` and also the version of socket.io of my server was 4.x while the version of the client was 2.x that was the cause.